# Error loading layer in QGIS using Iface

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

While I was trying to load a vector layer (Shapefile) from the desktop directory into the QGIS using the iface variable data is not loading and
user name in location of the status message is showing strange symbol
.Can anyone please suggest the solution.

Code is:

```
layer=iface.addVectorLayer("Users\bipin162\Desktop\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","ogr")
```

Error Received while loading:
[image]

the username needs to be like:
\Users\bipin162\Desktop\TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp

Comment: Dash `-` is unaccepted character in shapefile name.

Comment: Dash has been removed and renamed with simple name still same error is showing in QGIS staus bar.

Comment: You need to put `r` before the path. see the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using QGIS 3 you need to load the layers like this:

```
uri = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\Test4\TestGrid_Test.shp"
iface.addVectorLayer(uri, "Grid", "ogr")
```

You need to put `r` before the path. `r` stands for "raw" which interprets backslash in the string as actual backslash rather than a special character.

You can refer to the tutorial of [PyQGIS 101: Loading a vector layer](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-loading-a-vector-layer/)